# Outgoing Payments with check payment primary form items via DI-API

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

I'm trying to add an OP with **check payment** with a primary form item but after saving the payment the chosen CFWid won't reflect in SAP but instead shows the default cash flow.

I have successfully added an OP with Bank Transfer Primary form items, using the code below (both using same GL account - with cash flow relevant checked.)

```
oPay.PrimaryFormItems.CashFlowLineItemID = Int32.Parse(row["CFWId"].ToString());

if (row["PaymentMen"].ToString() == "BTR")
{
    oPay.PrimaryFormItems.PaymentMeans = PaymentMeansTypeEnum.pmtBankTransfer;
}
else if (row["PaymentMen"].ToString() == "CHK")
{
    oPay.PrimaryFormItems.PaymentMeans = PaymentMeansTypeEnum.pmtChecks;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

```
for (int c = 0; c < oPago.PrimaryFormItems.Count; c++) {
    oPago.PrimaryFormItems.SetCurrentLine(c);
    oPago.PrimaryFormItems.CashFlowLineItemID = PAFCId;
}
```